# Visiting UK while going through spouse visa application

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration

I am a Brazilian national living in the UK on a Tier 2 visa. I recently got married, and my wife, also Brazilian, is applying for a UK Tier 2 dependant visa.

She has already completed the online application and now the next step is to attend an appointment at the Visa Application Centre in Brazil to submit her biometrics and turn in her passport.

This appointment is in 4 weeks.

We booked a flight for her to fly from Brazil to the UK to visit me this week, returning to Brazil a couple days before her visa appointment.

**Question**: is she allowed to enter the UK as a visitor at this stage of the application process? Will she be denied entry?

Additionally, are there restrictions around Brazilians visiting the UK due to COVID-19, other than the 14 days quarantine?

Comment: She's not legally prohibited from visiting. However, a significant obstacle is that her husband is already in the UK, and she has applied for a dependent visa to join him. To secure a visitor entry, she must convince UK immigration that she'll leave when her visit is over. She should carry with her physical copies of her application file, especially including docs showing she has significant ties to Brazil: permanent employment, flat rental, and immediate family remaining in Brazil are the usual things looked for. All in all, however, I think she has a significant risk of being refused entry.

Comment: One addition: to the extent she can present herself calmly and consciously, she should acknowledge the issue. For instance, "I do want to join my husband on a Tier 2 dependent visa. I won't risk that by overstaying this tourist entry" would be a reasonable representation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, she will bring her application file.